# How to log SQL script lines in Delphi from TStringList to file

Tags: delphi

I use this code to log the many lines (SQL.Add) making complex scripts i have to build:

Ex:

```
[...]
SQL.Add('ENTITY_ID, PRO_CODE, PHASE_CODE, TASK_CODE, PERIOD_REF');
SQL.Add('from ' + trim(SourceJrnl) + ' where');
SQL.Add('MASTER_ID = ' + IntToStr(TranID) + ' and');...
[...]


{ for debugging only }
for i := 0 to SQL.Count-1 do 
  ShowMessage('Line #' + IntToStr(i+1) + ' : '+ SQL.Strings[i]);
```

Any simple way (function) to have the lines written to a file out of a stringlist or memo.

[EDIT] Sorry. NO memo or stringlist but a simple log file.

Comment: Your question make no sense. If you want this written in a memo, just write it there, or explain better what are you after.

Comment: MyMemo.Lines.Assign( SQL )

Comment: Sorry - i'm rather want the lines to be logged in a text file. It would be nice to have a log function or non visual component. thanks

Comment: SQL.SaveToFile?, or to append to an existing file SQL.SaveToStream(filestream)

Comment: edited question based on comments above. Volvox a bit more effort writing your question would be good.

Comment: OK thanks - SQL.SaveToFile will do the job. Since i have many different SQL scripts on the same unit i will do With SQL1 ... do SQL1.SQL.SaveToFile() ....etc.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `SQL.SaveToFile` will write the query to a file, but it will clobber the previous file contents, so you can only see one query and no other logs. Instead, read the `SQL.Text` property to get all the lines in a single string, and then write it to your log file using whatever logging technique you have for the rest of your program. In a pinch, a simple way to write a line of text to a file is to call `Writeln`, but [people have asked about real logging libraries before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72983/33732).