# Print in the console in Delphi Xe2 like in Java

Tags: java, delphi, console, delphi-xe2

I am working on a Delphi project for the first time, I used to develop on Java.

Is there a way to print in delphi's console like in java.

```
System.out.println("Message");
```

which I used to test code and find bugs (primitively).

Comment: Your question can be intepreted in at least two different ways. RRUZ talks about console-mode applications, while I talk about the IDE's event log (in any type of application). What exactly do you mean by "Delphi's console"?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand `System.out.println()` is the process console. `Writeln` in Delphi. `cout` in C++. `Console.WriteLine()` in C#. `print()` in Python. etc. etc.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks for clarifying. I was just about to look the Java stuff up.

Comment: `System.out.println()` shows in most IDEs when run in debug mode. I think the OP may want `OutputDebugString` to view messages when the application is run inside of Delphi IDE.

Comment: @Marcus: I also thought so, and wrote that as an answer half an hour ago. But most people believe the OP is after `Writeln`. But I'll undelete my answer so the OP can choose for himself.

Comment: Yeah, JVM has a debug console too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use [`Writeln`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Writeln) (only for console applications).

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
begin
  Writeln('Hello');
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: You can also call [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in a VCL application to use Writeln. Don't know about Firemonkey but it should work aswell on at least Windows.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to put a string in the IDE's event log, you can use the [`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the following code for "debugging" my programs.

```
    showmessage('Hello World');
```

That's how i do it.. :)

Comment: that's not what the OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something similar to Java console, you can use [CodeSite](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/codesite/), which uses an independent viewer

[image]

Another similar tool is [TraceTool](http://tracetool.sourceforge.net/)

[image]

More logging libraries on this question - [Which logging library is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72983/which-logging-library-is-better)

Answer (score 0):

For debugging messages there is also the GExperts console to which you can write using the SendXXX procedures in GX_DbugIntf. This unit is part of the GExperts source code which is available on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/gexperts/code/HEAD/tree/).